# How connection between powerapps and azure function?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

**Problem:-**
I have create a canvas app, where I upload file(image file) from PowerApps and store file in Blob Storage. I have also create a model which read image file from Blob storage and detect the object, After detecting object I want to show output in my PowerApps. I want to create a Tigger in my PowerApps,

**What I have done?**
I have create canvas app and successfully upload image on Blob storage by PowerApps. And  I am able to detect object from image by running  my python script in my local machine.

**Where I'm stuck??**
I don't know, how to trigger my python script from PowerApps? And show output in PowerApps.
please guide me, I'm new in Microsoft Services

Comment: Please edit your question with more details, including what you've tried, along with specific issues. Also please clarify the details around your python code: you said it's running via Azure Function - how is it triggered? What does it do? Where does its output go? As for Power Apps: Did you build a Canvas app? If so: Did you embed a report? Where does the report get its data from? I suspect you'd want it to get data from wherever your python code's output is going to, right?

Comment: Hi David makogon, Please guide me i have edit my question I think you can understand where i'm stuck ??

Comment: Well, right now this is still a bit broad. Seems like you need to host your python code somewhere and be able to pass info to it (e.g. the uri to the image), and get some text back describing it? There are lots of ways to do something like this, but perhaps start by looking at using an Azure Function, via Connector?

Comment: Yes David Makogon, You are right. I'm looking how to connect My Azure Function with PowerApps via connector. So that after tigger from PowerApps  my Azure function run And show the output in PowerApps Textbox.

Comment: I really don't know how I can help you. As I already explained, there are many ways to approach this type of challenge, and you still haven't really explained *exactly* what you've done and what your issues are. I suggest you edit your question to be very specific. At that point, perhaps someone will be able to help...